# C# Discord Embed Emoji Scraping

Tags: c#, web-scraping, discord

So I have set up a program that the goal of which is to run through every possible ID and test that ID to see if there is a discord emoji URL associated with it, if there is no emoji associated with that URL the website will not respond. Example link Below;

https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/1000000000000000001.png?v=1&size=100

However if there is an emoji associated with that URL, you will be able to see that emoji by following the link, example below;

https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/910272514863824951.png?v=1&size=100

Now I want to scrape all possible URL's for every working discord emoji link. If a working ID is found it is logged to a text file. If there is no response it is mentioned in the console and it keeps testing ID's.

Is there a way to speed this process up? I am still very new to C# and I am sure this could be quicker with better code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace Discord_Emoji_Scraper
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            start:
            using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
            
            try
            {
                if (id < 1000000000000000000)
                {
                    id++;
                    string WordID = "" + id;
                    string disurl = "https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/" + WordID + ".png?v=1&size=100";
                    if (WordID.Length < 18)
                    {
                        int diff = 18 - WordID.Length;
                        WordID += new string('0', diff);
                        
                    }
                    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(disurl) as HttpWebRequest;
                    request.Method = "HEAD";
                    HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
                    string filePath = @"G:\EmojisPng.txt";
                    string content = disurl;
                    using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(filePath))
                    {
                        outputFile.WriteLine(content);
                            Console.Write(id + " Does Work!");
                            goto start;
                    }

                }
                else if (id > 1000000000000000000)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Done");
                    return;
                }

            }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(id + " Not Work");
                    goto start;
                }
            
            
        }
        public static long id = 10000000000000000;

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know c, but I would use multithreading in python or aiohttp. but the real problem I wanna mention is not possible like this because discord is probably going to block your IP address so you need to buy a proxy and a lot of it.

Comment: The IDs are 18 characters long - you'll have to do billions of requests which is essentially a DDOS attack or will take years to finish. There has to be a list of available emojis somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

An issue here is the amount of times you're going to have to loop this, it's going to take a very long time regardless. In this code you're looping 990,000,000,000,000,000 times. If we assume each iteration takes exactly one millisecond to complete, this loop will only take a slight 31,478,937 years to complete. Not really good at this webclient stuff but you're probably gonna have to take a different approach.

TLDR: The current code is going to take 31,478,937 years to scrape every possible ID

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. The looping is what I am trying to speed up. Seeing as that it is only testing one link at a time, I wanted to speed that up maybe test multiple links at a time. A way to brute force the correct possible ID's without the denial of service onto discord servers : /

Comment: @BoomCode that would be nearly impossible to achieve. These IDs look like the [Discord snowflake format](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#snowflakes) (to be precise, it's Twitter's), though. You may be able to do something with that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Posted the code to GitHub if anyone wants to take a shot at making this a reality
[Github Repo](https://github.com/BoomSec/Discord-Emoji-Scraper)